# Node Express Multiple SQL server Connection

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, database-connection

I need to connect to diferent databases on direfent servers.
The servers are Microsoft SQL Server.

I do it like this:

> dbconfig.js

```
    var sql1 = require('mssql')
    var sql2 = require('mssql')

    var conn1 = {server:"SERVER IP", database:"db1", user:"foo", password:"foo", port:1433}

    var conn2= {server:"SERVER2 IP", database:"db2", user:"foo2", password:"foo2", port:1433}

var server1= sql1.connect(conn1)
    .then(function() {  debug('Connected'); })
    .catch(function(err) { debug('Error connect SQL Server', err);  });

    var server2= sql2.connect(conn2)
        .then(function() {  debug('Connected'); })
        .catch(function(err) { debug('Error connect SQL Server', err);  });

module.exports = {"ServerConn1": sql1, "ServerConn2": sql2};
```

After that, both connection are active, but when I do a query to the first connection it didn't work.

> The error is Invalid object name 'FooDatabase.dbo.fooTable'.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I implement using MySQL you can do the same thing mssql by passing empty database parameter and letter update database before creates connection.

And you do not need to import two-times just update the DB name before creating connection or query.

```
const express = 

require('express');  
const app = express();  
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',//here i am not passing db and db is undefined

});

app.get('/db1',function(req,res)
{
connection.config.database="task" //here  i updating db name before query
connection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks', function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(results)
    res.json(fields)
connection.end()
})
})

app.get('/db2',function(req,res)
{
connection.config.database="cg_taskview" //db2

connection.query('SELECT * FROM tasks', function (error, results, fields) {
     if (error)
    console.log(error); 
    console.log(results)
    res.json(fields)
     });
connection.end()

})

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port, function () { 
})
```

Comment: You are making the queries in the same server! I need to make queries on different servers at the same time.

I need to maintain the connections open!

Comment: Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Answer (score 1):

I started experiencing a similar problem when a second MSSQL server was added as a data source to the project ... Fortunately, I found a solution in the examples for *tediousjs*.
Just use the ConnectionPool and don't forget to close the connection:

```
const settings  = require('./config');
const sql = require('mssql');

exports.someSqlQuery = async function(sqlQuery) {
  const cPool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
  cPool.on('error', err => console.log('---> SQL Error: ', err));

  try {
    await cPool.connect();
    let result = await cPool.request().query(sqlQuery);
    return {data: result};
  } catch (err) { 
    return {error: err};
  } finally {
    cPool.close(); // <-- closing connection in the end it's a key
  }
};
```

If all of yours connections will have a **close** you can use the connections to different databases on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code for the testing:

```
var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const config = {server:'localhost', database:'TestDB', 
        options: { trustedConnection: true }};
const config2 = {server:'SomewhereNotExist', database:'TestDB', 
        options: { trustedConnection: true }};

(async () => {
  try { 
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let result = await pool.request().query('select count(1) as cnt from AlarmWithLastStatus');
    console.log('DB1 result:');
    console.dir(result.recordset);

    let pool2 = await sql.connect(config2);
    let result2 = await pool2.request().query('select count(1) as cnt from AlarmWithLastStatus');
    console.log('DB2 result:');
    console.dir(result2.recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  }
}) ();
```

The output:
DB1 result: [ { cnt: 12 } ]
DB2 result: [ { cnt: 12 } ]

You could see that the two connection actually points to the same server.
If you change the second query to a table that does not exist in this server, that will generate the error you got.

Comment: Welcome to SO! That is a comment rather than an answer. Please, edit it to become  a reply or wait to win some Rep for commenting. Some people will downvote you reply.

Comment: When i try the above code, I am able to connect to the first server without any issues . But when i try connecting to the second server I get Global connection already exists. Let me know if i need to do change something for connecting to more than one sql server from node js.